# Запрос с https на http, которого я не делею

Tags: javascript, https

делаю запрос на домен по https. Во вкладке networks вижу, что запрос уходит по https. Но в консоли сообщается странное

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://a.b.c.d/5f5127e27ea1d20d920abb7a' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://e.b.c.d/certificate/5f5127e27ea1d20d920abb7a'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

т.е. вообще говоря, почему-то запрос идёт по http и всё накрывается. В чём беда?

https://certificate.stage.fless.pro/5f5127e27ea1d20d920abb7a

---

Связанный вопрос: [Редирект uvicorn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1174606/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-uvicorn)

Comment: Если запрос блокируется, то во вкладке networks он вообще не отобразится, так что не совсем понятно о чём речь

Comment: Когда эта ошибка выскакивает? Что вы нажимаете? Что в коде находится, который отрабатывает по нажатии? У вас случаем не абсолютные ссылки на сайте?

Comment: покажи скриншоты с ошибкой и запросами

Comment: @Grundy прицепил ссылку

Comment: Ваш https-запрос возвращает 307 редирект на http-ссылку, которая и блокируется. Чините бэкенд

Comment: @andreymal какой? Бэкенд вот он, и он возвращает 200 https://certificate-backend.stage.fless.pro/certificate/5f5127e27ea1d20d920abb7a ?

Comment: @hedgehogues это не та ссылка, внимательно на вкладке networks посмотрите какая ссылка на самом деле

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1174606/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-uvicorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ответе на твой запрос бэкэнд выдает 307 редирект на хттп

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-length: 0
date: Sat, 05 Sep 2020 10:53:26 GMT
location: http://certificate-backend.stage.fless.pro/certificate/5f5127e27ea1d20d920abb7a
server: uvicorn
status: 307
```

js вызывает `URL: https://certificate-backend.stage.fless.pro/certificate/5f5127e27ea1d20d920abb7a/` а [сервер пытается убрать концевой слэш и редиректит на хттп](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/eedf36974186de9704839892378948f414748edd/starlette/routing.py#L580)

Такое может быть если хттп сервер не выдает нужные хидеры при проксипасс , или используется библиотека для бэк, которая этот хидер не понимет.

Comment: Так вы же ходите на http? C https такого нет

Comment: https://certificate-backend.stage.fless.pro/certificate/5f5127e27ea1d20d920abb7a

Comment: Только откуда 307 взялся? У меня 302, если по http ходить

Comment: с https захожу - в ответ 307 на http

Comment: @hedgehogues зацени слеш в конце в коде на жс

Comment: Очень странно, почему uvicorn редиректит с https на http

Comment: Зачем такое делать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1174606/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-uvicorn