# Редирект uvicorn

Tags: python, сервер, uvicorn

В чём причина редиректа, который выполняет uvicorn для [ресурса](https://certificate-backend.stage.fless.pro/certificate/5f5127e27ea1d20d920abb7a).

Если я отправляю запрос https://certificate-backend.stage.fless.pro/certificate/5f5127e27ea1d20d920abb7a/, тогда происходит серия редиректов.

## Запрос

```
https://certificate-backend.stage.fless.pro/certificate/5f5127e27ea1d20d920abb7a/

content-length: 0
date: Sat, 05 Sep 2020 15:50:34 GMT
location: http://certificate-backend.stage.fless.pro/certificate/5f5127e27ea1d20d920abb7a
server: uvicorn
status: 307
```

## Редирект 1 (status-code 302)

```
http://certificate-backend.stage.fless.pro/certificate/5f5127e27ea1d20d920abb7a

Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 05 Sep 2020 15:50:34 GMT
Location: https://certificate-backend.stage.fless.pro:443/certificate/5f5127e27ea1d20d920abb7a
```

## Редирект 2

```
https://certificate-backend.stage.fless.pro/certificate/5f5127e27ea1d20d920abb7a

content-length: 170
content-type: application/json
date: Sat, 05 Sep 2020 15:50:34 GMT
server: uvicorn
status: 200
```

Если запрос отправлять напрямую, тогда этого не происодит

Comment: Ну учитывая, что код uvicorn не содержит ни единого упоминания редиректов или кода 307, проблема в вашем коде, который вы не показали

Comment: @andreymal окей, попробуем воспроизвести на маленьком примере

Comment: бэк на чем? в аиохттп есть такой редирект

Comment: @eri fastapi юзает бэк.

Comment: @andreymal разумно. Но, затем, тот же uvicorn делает редирект на https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутренний телепат подсказывает что не хватает хидера `x-forwarded-proto` в прокси, которая делает хттпс  или бэк его не понимает.

/ в конце урл обрезает роутер бэкэнд сервера и делает редирект. uri собирается на основе хидеров или заколовков wsgi, asgi. Тут или бэкэнд не понимает что запрос проксирован или ssl-прокси не отдает хидер.

[вот в этом месте](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/eedf36974186de9704839892378948f414748edd/starlette/routing.py#L580) starlette(движок http в fastapi) убирает слеш в конце запроса.

Comment: Прокси отсутствует, судя по всему (или настолько неприметный, что я следов его существования не обнаружил)

Comment: А не, нашёл следы Traefik

Comment: как тогда сертификаты хттпс в увикорн засунуты?  ну пусть напрямую через wsgi/asgi протокол должен передаваться

Comment: Увикорн вполне поддерживает https и работу с сертификатами (впрочем, я уже нашёл следы Traefik)

Comment: @andreymal прокси есть. Да, traefik. Кстати, как Вы его заметили?

Comment: @eri сертификаты в traefik

Comment: @hedgehogues зашёл по айпишнику вместо домена, он и спалился. Ну а дальше Traefik, вероятно, забывает передавать в uvicorn информацию о том, что есть https, тот и не в курсе

Comment: Решил вопрос просто. https://certificate-backend.stage.fless.pro/certificate/5f5127e27ea1d20d920abb7a/
заменил на https://certificate-backend.stage.fless.pro/certificate/5f5127e27ea1d20d920abb7a . Всё заработало

Comment: @eri сертификаты выставлять в бэкенд, а не на реверс прокси, кажется, не самая клёвая идея.

Comment: https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/7affeae4801d9e3cfcccb7eb8f179f193d85d878/pkg/middlewares/forwardedheaders/forwarded_header.go#L142

в Traefik вроде все норм

Comment: @hedgehogues стыковка asgi?

Comment: В общем и целом, в traefik всё ок. Что понимается под стыковкой asgi?

Comment: увикорн-фастапи соединяются по асги обычно, но вроде можно и по-другому\